# Como plotar um grafico com ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho o seguinte data.frame:

```
                     sample OPN1SW  OPN1MW OPN1LW    RHO   OPN3   OPN4   OPN5
1: GTEX-11WQK-1026-SM-5EQLX  2.365  0.0000      0  4.138 86.322 40.199 12.533
2:  GTEX-XQ3S-1426-SM-4BOPR 22.317  0.0000      0 30.693 84.376 33.564  0.000
3:  GTEX-WHPG-2626-SM-3NMBR 21.142  0.6874      0 29.372 89.879 48.453  0.000
4:  GTEX-WEY5-2326-SM-3GIKK  0.000 16.2860      0 28.632 83.683 23.741  0.000
5: GTEX-14A5H-0826-SM-5QGPJ 20.448  0.0000      0 28.585 80.831 44.142 13.579
6: GTEX-132AR-0326-SM-5KM2C 12.052  0.0000      0 26.375 78.887 29.123 12.052
```

Dados Completos: https://pastebin.com/hSghfm2d

É uma pequena amostra de uma base de dados do Xena Browser (Bioinfo); As colunas são a expressão genica, enquanto as linhas são as amostras.

Preciso fazer um gráfico de `boxplot`, onde a expressão genica é o eixo `x` e os valores são o `y`

O problema é que não estou conseguindo fazer isso, tentei da seguinte maneira:

```
qplot(OPN1SW,sample,data = sk, geom='boxplot')
```

[image: Plot de grafico com ggplot]

Entretanto não é o que eu preciso; o que eu preciso é algo parecido com isso:

[image: Gráfico certo]

Os nomes do eixo X seriam os `samples` da minha tabela.
Eu imagino que estou errando o X e o Y na hora de plotar, mas não sei como resolver isso, pois cada coluna deve ser um `boxplot` com os devidos valores calculados. Como posso resolver isso? Grato pela ajuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O teu problema está na organização do data frame `sk`. O `ggplot2` é um pacote muito exigente com a forma dos dados a serem plotados. O ideal é que uma coluna possua todos os valores da expressão gênica e outra coluna possua todos os nomes dos genes.

Uma maneira prática de organizar os dados é através do comando `melt` do pacote `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)

sk_melt <- melt(sk)
```

Note que o data frame `sk_melt` possui 3 colunas:

- `sample`: autoexplicativa
- `variable`: com os nomes dos genes do conjunto de dados original
- `value`: com os valores das expressões gênicas associadas a cada gene, em cada amostra

Agora basta fazer o boxplot com o novo conjunto de dados `sk_melt`. Particularmente, não gosto do `qplot`. Acho que o gráfico fica mais organizado utilizando o `ggplot` por extenso. Assim, use os comandos a seguir e seu gráfico estará pronto:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(sk_melt, aes(x=variable, y=value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x="Gene", y="Expressão Gênica")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É isto mesmo que eu precisava, obrigado! Porém meu arquivo CSV tem pouco mais de 3GB, tentei transforma-lo com o mult() é da erro. Acredito que dê pra fazer em "blocos", de forma que não consuma toda a memória RAM; mas conhece alguma outra lib que dê para fazer sem usar o mult? Ou uma outra forma eficiente de fazer isto?

Comment: Tente usar o pacote `data.table` para ler os teus dados. Ele é mais eficiente em uso de memória do que os métodos tradicionais do `R`. [Aqui tem uma aplicação disso](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html).